# Cloudformation with OpsWorks handle empty value

Tags: json, aws-cloudformation, aws-opsworks

In my cloudformation template I have a Parameter that can be empty but with a Fn::Join assume a value, this is the example:

```
 "Parameters": {
  "ConfigureRecipe": {
   "Description": "Configure recipe.",
   "Type": "String"
  }

"Configure": [ { "Fn::Join": [ "", [ "myChefRecipe::", { "Ref": "ConfigureRecipe" } ] ] } ]
```

If ConfigureRecipe is empty, Cloudfomation will pass to OpsWorks the recipe "myChefRecipe::" and give me an error when configure start because a good variable is "myChefRecipe::mysql". How I can handle this? Maybe with AWS::NoValue if ConfigureRecipe is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this out:

```
    "Parameters": {
    "ConfigureRecipe": {
    "Description": "Configure recipe.",
    "Type": "String"
    }

   "Conditions" : {
"CreateLayerWithoutRecipie" : {"Fn::Not" : [{"Ref" : "ConfigureRecipe"}]}
    },

    "Layer":{
     "Type":"AWS::OpsWorks::Layer",
     ....
     ....
     ....
     "Configure": [ "Fn::If" : [ "CreateLayerWithoutRecipie", {"Ref" : "AWS::NoValue"}, { "Fn::Join": [ "", [ "myChefRecipe::", { "Ref": "ConfigureRecipe" }  ] ] } ]]
     }
```